# Open modal in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

In my react project, this is my **App**.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/modal">
            <Modal />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <p>
        Please <Link to="/modal/1">Click Here</Link> for see details.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you click on "Click Here", the modal was open, but my home page will be disappear. how can open this modal without destroying the home page ?

DEMO HERE:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-2g9t1

Comment: Switches only match a single route at a time, but even if you removed the `Switch`, the modal path wouldn't match the home path unless you remove the `exact` prop so it will always match. A better pattern would be to not put the modal in a route unless it is specific to that route.

Comment: Thanks. but i need to see a example.

Answer (score 0):

Modals should not be in a route as they are supposed to be on top of another page, not a page themshelves. If you want my opinion I would suggest you to put the modal in any of the pages and control if it is opened or not with a react state:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

    const Home = () => {
    const [ isModalOpened, setModalOpened ] = useState(false);

      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Home</h2>
          <button onClick={() => setModalOpened(!isModalOpened)}
          <Modal isOpened={isModalOpened}>
              ...modal content here
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

And your modal component should look like something like this:

```
const Modal = ({ isOpened, children }) => (
    <div>
        {
            isOpened &&
                { children }
        }
    </div>

)
```

If this helps you make sure to mark it as a good response!

Comment: Hi, Thanks.Can you edit my demo and make your change ?

Comment: Edited! That should work for you, if any problem just let me know!

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, but not work:
 https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-2g9t1